# A curve is a straight line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ if and only if..

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

A regular curve $\gamma(t)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a straight line iff $\gamma'$ and $\gamma''$ are proportional everywhere.

I am looking for a proof of this so I can understand what it is meaning.

So $\gamma' = m\gamma''$ for some scalar $m$ right? I'm not sure how this relates to a curve being a straight line.

Comment: Do you define straight line as $\gamma(t)=t\, v$, for a fixed $v\in \Bbb R^3$?

Comment: And what does "regular"  means in your context?

Comment: Indeed, what is your definition of a straight line? Surely it is characterized by the fact that its velocity vector (in any parametrization) never changes direction. Can you see that this happens if and only if $\gamma''$ is parallel to $\gamma'$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for an intuition:

Think at $\gamma'(t)$ as the velocity of a point moving along the trajectory $\gamma(t)$. So $\gamma''(t)$ is the acceleration of the point. If the acceleration is always aligned with the velocity, i.e. $\gamma''(t)=k\gamma'(t) \; \forall t$ than the velocity has always the same direction and this means that the trajectory is straight line.

Comment: I understand now! Thank you.